# Android Facebook SDK share via a page

Tags: android, facebook

I want my app to be able to make a share on Facebook which will appear as a link via my page (to give my Facebook page credit). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried two ways

1. Official facebook SDk implementation, which is little bit complecated.
2. EasyFacebookImplementation which is very easy.

Try my answers here.

[How to integrate Facebook in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357811/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-my-android-application/15520199#15520199)