# LoginWithFacebook from android app

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-login

I'm an Android developer. I developed my first helloWorld app, but I have some problems with creating a facebook session.

I followed many tutorials... For example: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html

I've added a LoginButton in my activity and created a session handler. The Handler is called but the session is never open. Why?

Step 1.
Click on button
{Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:15xxxxxxxxxxxxx}

Step 2.
User accept condition...
{Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:15xxxxxxxxxxxxx}

I generate the hash code and insert it into my registered app in Native Android App (Key Hashes).

When I generate the hash, I set a random password, Is it ok?

Comment: This may be helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357811/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-my-android-application/15520199#15520199

Answer (score 2):

You have inserted the app-id of your application of facebook in the AndroidManifest.xml? 
You can obtain bud data seeing this tutorial (in your case, with special attention to step 6):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Good luck!!