# Facebook login/logout

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app through which I will have to login/logout of facebook. Is there a way such that, the process of login/logout to facebook through my app is not dependent on the login/logout through the official facebook app?

Comment: integrate facebook to your app without SSO.

Comment: Here is the very easy way to use facebook integration
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357811/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-my-android-application/15520199#15520199

Answer (score 2):

You can login and logout programatically using facebook sdk 3.0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-logout-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-logi) for example), but you can't escape being redirected to a facebook login UI if the user isn't logged in already.

Comment: Hi, Atleast is there a way to check within my app, if the user has logged out of facebook through the official facebook app?

Comment: of course, the sdk will redirect you to the facebook UI for checkin and bring you back to the app