# Registration with Gmail / Facebook credentials in an Android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, gmail

I have an android  app which is having a registration page. In that  I want to integrate with Gmail and Facebook separately .So that user dont have to register themselves with new credentials .They can use Gmail or Facebook login id and password to login themselves.
As I am new to Android .kindly give some solution Step wise .Thanks in advance

Comment: Read this page to find out how to use account manager on anroid http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: thanks Robin . Can you provide me with some good example  how to use it.

Comment: Hey did you get any working example of registration with gmail? If yes then can you please share because I am also looking for the same and am not able to get any. Thanks

Comment: After digging up many sites got some idea of doing integration with google+ .Even I am working on this .Once completed I will share my code wid u .Till that Follow these links. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID   ,                         https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the very easy way to integrate facebook SDKs with android code.

1. Official facebook integration document
2. Easy facebook integration.

[How to integrate Facebook in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357811/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-my-android-application/15358228#15358228)

Comment: Hi Swapnil thanks your code is working perfectly when I am giving my username and password but Some error its showing when I want any other person to login into fb .why is so happening .Can u explain .....

Comment: Hi Swapnil your code is not working if fb app is installed in phone .After uninstalling fb app its started working . Do you have any idea about why its happening like this ?

Comment: Please go through official documentation instead of easy facebook one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to like a  **Single SignOn**  for `Facebook` you have to use Facebook android sdk that is available at `facebook developer` site for android for `Google Accoun`t authentication you should follow [this](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/)

Comment: Hi Abhijeet thanks .Actually that documentation i am not able to understand.can you please give any Sample code or more easy link to understand and implement.

Comment: can you please give any working example of Google Account authentication